# Replace #site-title with resizable image in Twenty Twelve?

Tags: theme-development

I've been wracking my brain with this all afternoon. I successfully replaced #site-title with an image using CSS, and it looks fine when browsing on a desktop, but i'd like to have the entire site be responsive (i'm using twenty twelve after all!).

The thing is, in order to replace #site-title in CSS, you have to apply fixed dimensions. Using "100%", "auto", etc just wipes the image from the page entirely. I've also attempted to add "width: 100%;" to #page, it's parent, to no avail.

Any ideas?.

Answer (score 1):

Again and again I see templates using H1 as a image background with nothing within the Tag itself, while this isn't bad SEO it's not good either. A header tag should be TEXT and be readible by Google and other search engines.

If you take a look at your

your see that there is nothing in it - You should resolve this first off by using a text indent.

Correct Your H1

```
<h1><a class="customlogo" href="http://www.ctwinvestmentgroup.org/" title="Return Home">CTW Investment Group<a></h1>
```

Add this to your CSS

```
.customlogo {
    background: url("http://www.ctwinvestmentgroup.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/CtWDiamond3.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 101px;
    width: 500px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    display: block;}
```

Now for Responsive to work with Background images you have 2 options to serve a different image for each device size or serve the same image but resized.

To do this you use Media Queries

Devices Below 768px we divide the logo by 2/3's

```
@media (max-width:768px){
.customlogo {
    height: 67px;
    width: 333px; }    
}
```

Devices Below 480 we half the logo

```
@media (max-width:480px){
.customlogo {
    height: 51px;
    width: 250px; }
}
```

Additional Notes:

Your site is not working as responsive presently since you are blocking it with a fixed size.

Remove

```
#page {
width: 960px;
}
```

And the responsive will start working again :P Hope this helps and remember H1's are not IMAGES! as so many people try to do, use a H1 a href with image and text for best SEO :P

Enjoy

Comment: +1 for "header tag should be TEXT and be readible by Google and other search engines"

Comment: thanks! Yea I decided to add a fixed width until I figure this out. I'll try your suggestions, but that seems spot on!

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to worker in conjuction with my header.php code, where I have for h1: <h1 class="site-title" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.ctwinvestmentgroup.org/'" style="cursor: pointer;"></h1> This is to link the logo to the home page.

Comment: Remove <h1 class="site-title" onclick="window.location.href='ctwinvestmentgroup.org/'"; style="cursor: pointer;"></h1> and use mine that I listed. Basiclly onclick on the H1 tag is making that H1 clickable. I have made it so its a H1 A href link which is clickable, and cursor:pointer attribute just tells the browser its a link, again my H1 tag I listed has this so just use all my code :P

Comment: Use the code I gave you and ignore what's there and replace it all.