# Elements floating on top of each other when Resizing or checking site on mobile. Twenty Twelve

Tags: mobile, responsive, theme-twenty-twelve, browser-compatibility

I'm using WP Twenty Twelve theme for my blog: [Glory and Honor](http://blog.gloryandhonor.com) and have followed the  [Replace #site-title with resizable image in Twenty Twelve Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78607/replace-site-title-with-resizable-image-in-twenty-twelve) to fix my logo not displaying when visiting via my mobile. (This is my first isssue)

I've been struggling with having my blog layout and site-logo display properly on my iPhone and iPad. The @media CSS (from the posting I have been following) disappears my site-logo altogether.

Also, I have been working on the CSS for the actual site-logo but noticed that when I remove the margins from the site-logo CSS, the logo does display on my mobile and the layout looks fine. The problem is, I do need the margins because the logo displays exactly how I want it to - centered in the header - for the desktop version.

Another issue is the sign up form, search form, and shop image-button/ link I have added. They float all over the place on the desktop site (when resizing the browser) and when visiting the site via my mobile.

I absolutely would like to keep the site responsive.

Comment: Hi CG, CSS questions are usually considered off-topic here, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help